# Fuel Efficiency vs Engine capacity

Tags: engine, honda, suzuki, efficiency

How come there are cars with 1500cc engine producing with better fuel efficiency than a 800cc motorcycle with roughly the same amount of bhp?

For example a Suzuki Splash with 1200cc and 87bhp returns 15km/liter while as a Honda CBR 250r with 25 bhp return only 20km/l.

Someone please explain the concept.

Comment: According to [Honda's webpage](http://powersports.honda.com/2013/cbr250r/specifications.aspx), the 2012/2013 CBR250R gets 32.74 km/l (or 77 mpg). I'm not sure your example is a very good one, which makes your question unclear.

Comment: Well according to the page yes it says so , but i have 4 friends of mine who have 250rs and not one of them gets anything close to that

Comment: CBR 150R on normal city traffic gives you around 35km/l , honda claims around 45kmpl lmfao